# Cannot install g++-10

Tags: apt, gcc, g++

Running Ubuntu 18.04. I have added ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test.

I have successfully installed gcc-10:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gcc-10 is already the newest version (10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04).
```

I have also installed g++-7:

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++-7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
g++-7 is already the newest version (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04).
```

Bit I cannot install g++-10:

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++-10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'clang-10-examples' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'clang-10' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'libclang-10-dev' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-10' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'clang-10-doc' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'python3-clang-10' for regex 'g++-10'
clang-10 is already the newest version (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1~18.04.1).
clang-10-doc is already the newest version (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1~18.04.1).
clang-10-examples is already the newest version (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1~18.04.1).
libclang-10-dev is already the newest version (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1~18.04.1).
python3-clang-10 is already the newest version (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1~18.04.1).
```

What could be the problem?

Edit:

after doing `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`:

```
$ apt policy '^gcc-10$' '^g\+\+-10$'
gcc-10:
  Installed: 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04
  Candidate: 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04
  Version table:
 *** 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package ^g\+\+-10$
N: Couldn't find any package by regex '^g\+\+-10$'
```

Running the command with a plain query `g++-10` results in showing every package that matches the regex, but NO g++10.

Comment: That's odd - the only thing I can suggest is you run `sudo apt-get update` (or `sudo apt update`) again and then [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy gcc-10 g++-10`

Comment: @steeldriver updated

Comment: OK well sorry I am unable to reproduce this - an amd64 version of `10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04` is clearly present in the PPA and installs correctly for me. You don't have some kind of local cache or apt-mirror setup I suppose?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm completely baffled now, because sometimes I can see g++10 and sometimes I cannot. Moreover, when I managed to install g++-10 during a window of visibility, something has removed it without telling me. I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: On older releases of Ubuntu, APT would treat `g++-10` as regex when there's no package with such name available. On one hand, it seems PPA is enabled while OTOH it seems PPA is disabled. What is the output of `lz4 -d /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-toolchain-r_test_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4 | grep "g++-10"`? If `lz4` isn't available, you can install it with `apt install liblz4-tool`.

Comment: @steeldriver found the culprit... see answer

Comment: It has installed clang-10 compiler, try to use the command 'clang' or 'clang-10'

Comment: @turbulence clang does not support c++20 features I need

Comment: If you can afford to keep your computer on for 5-6 hours, you can try to compile g++-10 from source by following this article - https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: This ppa has g++-10 for Ubuntu-20.04 only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that my computer at work is managed by [puppet](https://puppet.com/). I had no idea.

Apparently somebody in the IT has changed the central configuration recently. Now puppy removes my PPA and force-installs specific versions of certain packages every now and then.

Comment: You mean puppy linux?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no. https://puppet.com/